# php dependency injection in method not working

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am trying to get use dependency injection in methods via type hint.  its not working for me. calling `$container->get(Name::class);` works

```
  if (false === file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php')) {
            die('Install the composer dependencies');
        }
        
        require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
        
        
        //(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__) . '/.env');
        
        /* Load external routes file */
        require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/routes.php';
        
        $builder = new DI\ContainerBuilder();
        $builder->addDefinitions(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/Definitions.php');
        try {
            $builder->useAutowiring(true);
            $container = $builder->build();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        
        function test(Cache $cache)
        {
            dd($cache);
        }
        test();
        
        die;
```

The Definitions file

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/config.php';

return [
    Cache::class => DI\create(Cache::class)->constructor(MEMCACHED_SERVERS),
    
    \Twig\Environment::class => function () {
        $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(dirname(__DIR__) . '/Views/');
        $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
            'cache' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/Cache/'

        ]);

        return $twig;
    },

];
```

The error i am getting :

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function test(), 0 passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because you made the `test` function require `Cache` then when you run `test()` you don’t inject the `Cache` object here:

```
function test(Cache $cache)
{
    dd($cache);
}

// here you need to pass instance of Cache
test();
```

I am not familiar with this code base, but you would either need an auto-injection script based on Reflection, or what-have-you, to do that auto-injection or you need to manually pass the `Cache` object:

```
test(new Cache);
```

If the `Cache` object uses all static methods or class constants, you don't need to create it injectable, you would just use it where it's required as in the script referenced by `Cache::class`;

One last possibility is that `$cache` is available in some `include` in one of those files somewhere, though I don't see that anywhere, but if that is available, you could make a `test()` a variable function with `use()`:

```
$test = function() use ($cache)
{
    dd($cache);
};

// No injection needed
$test();
```